# is this method object.keys returning an array or keep it an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, typeof

I'm learning JavaScript, so pardon any mistakes in how I phrase the question.

```js
let nan={
    n:3,
    j:4
};

let nag = Object.keys(nan)

> nag
(2) ["n", "j"]0: "n"1: "j"length: 2__proto__: Array(0)

> typeof nag
"object"
```

Why is `nag` an object and not an array? And that makes difference when you want to access, you will be not able to access with dot notation I think we need in that case square bracket

Comment: typeof of an array is "object"

Comment: Because there is no Array [type](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-types). Arrays are objects, see [*typeof* operator](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-typeof-operator).

Comment: It is an array only; Everything in js is object

Comment: Use [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) to check if an object is an actual array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because internally javascript engines store Arrays as objects. Therefore, when you ask for the `typeof` an array, it returns an `object` since that is what it is. Essentially, in javascript, `Array` is an abstraction over native `object` (an `indexed collection` object).

If you want to know whether a variable is an `Array` and not an `object` you should use `Array.isArray(nag)`. This returns a `boolean`.

You can lookup the docs here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray

or if you are in the mood, lookup the `typeof` spec at:

https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-typeof-operator

> tip: With JS, whenever in doubt, lookup the specs. It's probably the best place to clear up confusions

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, everything that is not a primitive (numbers, bigints, strings, symbols) are objects. This includes arrays. Objects also have square bracket notation to look up a key, and the dot notation is just a shorthand for looking up a string key:

```js
const a = {
    foo: "bar"
};
a.foo // "bar"
a["foo"] // "bar"
```